# Group rows by date with count and enumerate rows in the resultset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have a data in a table, column id and column date

```
id  || date
1   || 2013-04-18 15:12:32.000  
2   || 2013-04-18 15:13:02.000  
3   || 2013-05-01 19:09:28.000  
4   || 2013-05-01 19:09:46.000  
5   || 2013-05-01 19:10:01.000  
6   || 2013-05-01 19:10:17.000  
7   || 2013-05-02 08:34:54.000  
8   || 2013-05-02 08:35:12.000  
9   || 2013-05-18 15:12:32.000   
10  || 2013-05-18 15:13:02.000
```

how query to show only one day with count?or one row with count. so the result is.

```
    || date                    ||
1   || 2013-04-18 15:12:32.000 ||  2
2   || 2013-05-01 19:09:28.000 ||  4
3   || 2013-05-02 08:34:54.000 ||  2
4   || 2013-05-18 15:13:02.000 ||  2
```

i try in mysql and it works , there is my query.

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT( date ) AS date, COUNT( id ) AS count
FROM petak_tetap
GROUP BY DATE( date )
```

but when i try to sql server 2008, this query error

here is the error message

```
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
'GROUP_CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

how to fix that?

Comment: There are [already **over two hundred** questions (and answers!)](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+server+group_concat) for that topic here on this site.... just pick one ....

Comment: OP's question has nothing to do with `GROUP_CONCAT`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all there is no `GROUP_CONCAT` function in SQL Server but more importantly you don't need in your case the functionality this function provides. Use aggregate function `MIN()` or `MAX()` to get one datetime value per group.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY [date]) No, [date], [count]
FROM 
(SELECT MIN([date]) 'date', 
        COUNT(*) 'count'
   FROM petak_tetap
  GROUP BY CAST([date] AS DATE)
) t
```

Output:

```
| NO |                         DATE | COUNT |
---------------------------------------------
|  1 | April, 18 2013 15:12:32+0000 |     2 |
|  2 |   May, 01 2013 19:09:28+0000 |     4 |
|  3 |   May, 02 2013 08:34:54+0000 |     2 |
|  4 |   May, 18 2013 15:12:32+0000 |     2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d3f13/18)** demo

**UPDATE** In sqlite

```
SELECT 
 (
   SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM 
   ( SELECT 1
       FROM petak_tetap
      WHERE id <= t.id
      GROUP BY DATE(date)
   ) q
 ) No, date, count
  FROM 
 (
   SELECT id, MIN(date) date, COUNT(*) count
     FROM petak_tetap
    GROUP BY DATE(date)   
 ) t
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/3a90b/26)** demo

Comment: how about in sqlite? @peterm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837958/group-concat-and-how-to-use-row-number-in-sqlite how to fix it? @peterm

Comment: @Alexbelek See updated answer and sqlfiddle.

Comment: @Alexbelek And the answer for another question is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16849618/1920232

Comment: yes i see it. thanks for helping me. i think the function `ROW_NUMBER () ` is only work in sql server. CMIIW @peterm

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY DATE) SNo, DATE, COUNT(DATE)AS Count FROM Table
GROUP BY DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select p1.date,
      (select count(p2.date) from petak_tetap p2 where p2.date=p1.date)
from petak_tetap p1 group by p1.date
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This One With Complete Output In One Query Only..**

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order BY Min(IDate)) srno,  Min(IDate) idate, COUNT(*) Cnt
FROM grpcontact
GROUP BY CONVERT(Varchar,IDate,101)
```

**OutPut** >>>

```
------------------------------------
srno | idate                   | Cnt
------------------------------------
1    | 2013-04-18 15:12:32.000 | 2
2    | 2013-05-01 19:09:28.000 | 4
3    | 2013-05-02 08:34:54.000 | 2
4    | 2013-05-18 15:12:32.000 | 2
------------------------------------
```