# group_concat and how to use row number in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite, group-concat

i have a data in a table, column id and column date

```
id  || datetime
1   || 2013-05-24 19:23:16
2   || 2013-05-28 19:24:20
3   || 2013-05-28 19:25:05  
4   || 2013-05-30 19:25:39  
5   || 2013-05-30 19:26:05
```

how query to show only one day with count?or one row with count. so the result is.

```
    || datetime            || count
1   || 2013-05-24 19:23:16 ||  1
2   || 2013-05-28 19:24:20 ||  2
3   || 2013-05-30 19:25:39 ||  2
```

i try in mysql and it works , there is my query.

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT( datetime ) AS date, COUNT( id ) AS count
FROM dataPetak
GROUP BY DATE( datetime )
```

but when i use sqlite the result is gives me all in one string

```
5 || 2013-05-24 19:23:16,2013-05-28 19:24:20,2013-05-28 19:25:05,2013-05-30 19:25:39,2013-05-30 19:26:05 || 5
```

how to fix that?

help me

**EDIT**

when i use query

```
SELECT [datetime], [count] FROM (SELECT MAX([datetime]) 'datetime', COUN
T(*) 'count' FROM dataPetak GROUP BY CAST ([datetime] AS DATE)) t;
```

the result is

```
       2013-05-24 19:23:16 ||  1
       2013-05-28 19:24:20 ||  2
       2013-05-30 19:25:39 ||  2
```

how to use row number in sqlite?

so the result is

```
1   || 2013-05-24 19:23:16 ||  1
2   || 2013-05-28 19:24:20 ||  2
3   || 2013-05-30 19:25:39 ||  2
```

when i try this query ,

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY [datetime]) No, [datetime], [count] FROM (SELECT MAX([datetime]) 'datetime', COUN
T(*) 'count' FROM dataPetak GROUP BY CAST ([datetime] AS DATE)) t;
```

show the error

```
Error: near "(": syntax error
```

how to fix that?

Comment: Your first query works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for `GROUP_CONCAT()` functionality in your case. Your last query in the question is for SQL Server. Sqlite doesn't have implementation for `ROW_NUMBER()`.

This being said, try

```sql
SELECT 
 (
   SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM 
   ( SELECT 1
       FROM dataPetak
      WHERE id <= t.id
      GROUP BY DATE(datetime)
   ) q
 ) No, datetime, count
  FROM 
 (
   SELECT id, MIN(datetime) datetime, COUNT(*) count
     FROM dataPetak
    GROUP BY DATE(datetime)   
 ) t
```

Output:

```
| No |            datetime | count |
------------------------------------
|  1 | 2013-05-24 19:23:16 |     1 |
|  2 | 2013-05-28 19:24:20 |     2 |
|  3 | 2013-05-30 19:25:39 |     2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/e3689/2)** demo

Comment: @PujaSury Do you need more help with your question?

Comment: yes, i think there's no need for `GROUP_CONCAT()` here is my query before i update with your answer `SELECT _id, date(date) AS date, COUNT(*) 'count' from tbl where idDb=" + rowID + " GROUP BY DATE (date);` now your answer it works perfectly. awesome. @peterm

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select date(datetime) as date,  count(*) as count from tbl 

group by date(datetime)
```

### **[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/cbe2c/3)**

```
|       date | count |
----------------------
| 2013-05-24 |     1 |
| 2013-05-28 |     2 |
| 2013-05-30 |     2 |
```